# Clustering/load balancing strategies using JBoss

Tags: jboss

I´ve studied about clustering and load balancing in JBoss and I liked two options in particular: mod_cluster and HAProxy.

I´ve already read both documentations and need to decide which one to choose.

What would be your choice and why?

Regards,
Rafael Roque

Comment: A data point:

WildFly ships with mod_cluster, OpenShift uses HAProxy.

WildFly clustering explained at: http://blog.arungupta.me/2014/03/wildfly-8-clustering-and-session-failover/

OpenShift + HAProxy: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-haproxy-scales-openshift-apps

Comment: Hi Arun,thanks for the heads up!My problem is,we have one application which is a dependency for many others,so we are considering some modularization approaches for it,like RMI or EJB.What would be the best choice in your opinion?

Comment: Can you start a new question for that and let me know ?